# How can I edit a row in mySQL table using AJAX/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a mySQL table with entries each having an input ID and input text; can somebody help me fix this PHP/AJAX code so that I can edit the input text of the entries.

PHP CODE:

```
$inputID = $_POST['inputID'];
$inputtxt = $_POST['inputtxt'];

$strSql = "UPDATE Contributions SET $inputID = '$inputID',       $inputtxt='inputtxt' WHERE id = '$id'"
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
    $( "#EDITsave" ).click(function() {
    console.log("console")
    var index = document.getElementById("editinputtext").value;   
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit.php",
    data: {inputID: id, inputtxt:index},
    dataType: "text",
    success:function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
   });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: `SET $inputID = '$inputID',       $inputtxt='inputtxt'` are you sure you got those right? and where's the HTML for this? and where `$id` comes from

Comment: can you please show me how to use these properly?

Comment: Assuming that you have the same names for both the HTML form and database columns, it would be `"UPDATE Contributions SET inputID = $inputID, inputtxt = $inputtxt WHERE id = $id"`, though you aren't actually passing through an `$id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**

- Here is the PHP code, hope this works

**

```
$inputID = $_POST['inputID'];
$inputtxt = $_POST['inputtxt'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

/* Prepare statement */
$query = "UPDATE Contributions SET inputtxt=? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param($inputtxt, $inputID);

/* Execute the statement */
try{ 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
return;
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

echo 'Record updated';

mysqli_close($link);
```